# Ethereum Mining 3 Geforce 1070

Tags: mining, ether, linux

If someone would mine with three GeForce 1070 cards on Ubuntu 16.04, is it necessary to plugin the SLI bridges?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use SLI or CrossFire.  The miner application should independently utilize each and every GPU.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would slow down your hash rate. allow the application to run each card.